# Force image to stay on the same line as text

Tags: html, css, joomla

I'm currently working on a Joomla website and have a custom HTML block in the header to display a phone number and email with icons next to them.

This works fine, however when you resize the page and make it smaller there is a point where the image will move to a different line which looks terrible,

```html
<p style="float: right;"><img src="/images/email_envelope.png"> email@email.com</p>
```

This is what I'm using.

I have also tried using display:inline-block but the same issue happens.

I have another of these above, with a smaller string of text but the same code and it works okay.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: double-check if in all view ports have both (img and text) same line-height and same vertical-align. If img is bigger than line-height, it could move everywhere... it depends on browser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need `white-space` CSS property.

> The white-space property controls how text is handled on the element
>   it is applied to.
>
> https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/whitespace/

MDN Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

Comment: It's not that small. It's around iPad size this happens as there are multiple custom HTML modules on the same line.

white-space: nowrap; worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can make it not wrap doing this but I don't like that approach because it may cause scrolling or just not show everything.

```html
<p style="float: right; white-space: nowrap;"><img src="/images/email_envelope.png"> email@email.com</p>
```

You could also hide the image when the window shrinks below a certian width: 600px in this example:

```css
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  #emailImg{
    display:none;
  }
}
```

```html
<p style="float: right;"><img id="emailImg" src="/images/email_envelope.png"> email@email.com</p>
```